# Markdown to get resource in "v1" version of the API with Apiary

Tags: apiary.io

I'd like to have an API documentation segmented per version of the API.
So my host is: http://api.clementlevallois.net/apitest/

The api version is: v1

The resource is: get/{id}

And I'd like the doc to generate:

http://api.clementlevallois.net/apitest/v1/get/{id}

But the "v1" part is squeezed and I just get: http://api.clementlevallois.net/apitest/get/{id}

Here is my markdown:

```
FORMAT: 1A
HOST: http://api.clementlevallois.net/apitest/


# API Test

"ApiTest" is a simple API I created to learn for myself how to create, publish and document APIs.

At the moment it is very basic:
type: http://api.clementlevallois.net/apitest/v1/get/YOUR NAME HERE

And check what it returns.

## Version 1 [/v1/]
Resource representing *the version 1* of the API.

### Request a greeting [GET /get/{username}]

+ Parameters
    + username (text, required) - The name that will be greeted.


+ Response 200 (application/json)

        {"username":"username"}
```

How can I get the "v1" part inserted in the URI?

Comment: Maybe this could be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32419425/does-apiary-io-and-or-api-blueprint-support-api-versioning

Comment: indeed, thank you. Versioning is one best practice of designing apis and this should probably be taken into consideration in the doc: different blueprints for different versions of the same api does not sound right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the blueprint is about `v1` only, it's inherently part of where it's location, therefore it should be included in `HOST`:

`HOST: http://api.clementlevallois.net/apitest/v1/`